# Errors are overriding other components

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In my page Errors and warning section is in top. When Errors are increasing, They are overriding other components which is preventing to use components.
I can handle 3-4 errors but they can come like 20-21. for this much error it is pain to write code .
Please suggest any dynamic approach that can be done so errors always come on top components like this.
[image: This is how i want]

[image: This is what i am getting now]

This is what i am getting now when error length are high

```
if (response.errors.length) {
          this.error = true;
          this.success = false;
          this.messages = response.errors;
          this.submitDisabled = true;
         if (response.errors.length === 3 && accountType === null) {
          nameAddressType.style.marginTop = '37px';
          contactInfoType.style.marginTop = '37px';
        } else if (response.errors.length === 2 && accountType === null) {
          nameAddressType.style.marginTop = '17px';
          contactInfoType.style.marginTop = '17px';
        }
```

}

Comment: Place the errors in the layout before the actual page content and make sure they are not using float or fixed or absolute positioning but regular static positioning.

Comment: Can you please little bit elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

t's simple. Have a dedicated div for the errors in the layout.

```
<div id="menu-container"></div>
<div id="error-contaienr"></div>
<div id="application-container"></div>
```

give a max-height and  min-height and set the overflow to auto for  error-container. After that populate the error in the container. it will scale till the max-height and  will start scrolling after that.

```
.error-container {
  position:relative; /*any other wont fit you use case*/
  max-height:300px; /*max height you want the error widget to take*/
  min-height: 30px; /*assuming you have a header to display, it can be 0*/
  overflow:auto;
}
```